# Applying patches across repositories with different commit histories

Tags: git, diff, patch

Let's say I have two repositories A and B that are similar, but different commit histories.

An example might be two Python Flask applications, or two Ruby on Rails applications that share a *lot* of similar files but are not quite identical.

I made a change on repository A that I'd like to also apply to repository B. There might be a few conflicts in applying it to B, but that's ok, I'd like to see what they are and work through them.

I tried the following to generate the patch from repo A

```
> cd ~/git/repoA/
> git format-patch HEAD~
0001-My-Example-Commit.patch
> mv 0001-My-Example-Commit.patch ~/git/repoB
```

And then I tried applying the patch to repo B

```
> cd ~/git/repoB
> git am 0001-My-Example-Commit.patch
Applying: My Example Commit
error: patch failed: Gemfile:20
error: Gemfile: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: Gemfile.lock:125
error: Gemfile.lock: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:29
error: app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss: patch does not apply
....
....
error: patch failed: spec/views/application/_mobile_navigation.html.erb_spec.rb:44
error: spec/views/application/_mobile_navigation.html.erb_spec.rb: patch does not apply
Patch failed at 0001 Using Devise for authentication
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
```

As shown, it results in several errors/conflicts. That's fine, I'll just try to see what the conflicts are and fix them, like I would do on a regular merge:

```
git status
On branch test-git-apply
You are in the middle of an am session.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git am --continue")
  (use "git am --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git am --abort" to restore the original branch)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Git does not even apply the changes as a diff, so there are no diffed/modified files and I cannot even see what the conflicts are or attempt to fix them

**Is there a way to force git to show the conflicts?**

Thanks!

**Edit**:

I know the `--directory` option exists but I don't think it applies here since my patch file is already generated relative to the same root. E.g.

```
diff --git a/Gemfile b/Gemfile
index c970c34..ffc812d 100644
--- a/Gemfile
+++ b/Gemfile
@@ -20,12 +20,17 @@ gem "webpacker", "~> 3.5", ">= 3.5.5"
 #
 gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1", ">= 3.1.10"
 gem "cancancan", "~> 3.0"
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no *conflicts*.<sup>1</sup>  The patch simply failed to apply.  For instance, the patch might say: *Line 87 reads "foo". On subsequent line 88, change "bar" to "baz".  Line 89 reads "quux".*  But your lines 87 through 89 do not read "foo" and "bar" and "quux", and there are no nearby lines that contain that sequence either.  It's up to you, the programmer, to figure out what to do with the patch.

> ```
> hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
> ```

So, use it.  Read the patch.  Inspect your files and decide how to treat this patch.

---

<sup>1</sup>There cannot be conflicts here, as a patch itself does not represent two *different* sets of changes to the same lines.  A conflict occurs when you have *two* diffs: one says to change bar to baz on line 88 (which is possible), and the other says to change bar to rab on line 88 (which is also possible).  The two changes conflict.

A patch supplies just *one* change.  It either applies, or does not.

---

#### Alternatives to patching

There are two alternative options here.  From less-effective to more-effective order:

- Be sure the patch from repo A was generated by a `git format-patch --full-index`.  When using `git am`, use `git am -3` (or configure `am.threeWay` to `true`).  That way, the diff on `A` will include the full blob hash of the parent version of the file.  If that blob—the parent's version of the file—is available in repo B, Git will be able to use the blob-hash-and-patch to reconstruct the three inputs that a real merge requires: a common base version and both modified-from-base versions.
- Or, use `git remote add` in repo B to add direct access to repo A.  Pick  a remote-name that will remind you what this is for later (or delete the remote immediately afterward).  Then run `git fetch` with this remote-name to bring the commits from repo A into repo B, so that all of the commits are available locally within B.  Now, instead of `git format-patch` and `git am`, you can just run:

  ```
  git cherry-pick <hash>
  ```

  for the commit in question.  Git will now do a full three-way merge, using the two commits from repo A as merge-base and their-change:

  ```
  git diff <parent of hash> <hash>   # what they changed
  ```

  and your current commit as your-change:

  ```
  git diff <parent of hash> HEAD     # what we changed
  ```

  and combine them, with conflicts as appropriate.  The second diff command here is "what we changed" or the `--ours` part of the merge; the first diff command here is "what they changed" and hence the `--theirs` part of the merge.

Note that `git am -3`, or setting `am.threeWay`, is merely a method of *attempting* the full merge by hoping that the:

```
index a1539a7ce682f10a5aff3d1fee4e86530e058c89..98f88a28d3227c436ecf1765f75b7f4e8e336834 100755
```

gives a hash ID that appears in your repository.  Doing the `git fetch` actually *gets* you the blob with that hash ID, if you don't already have it, so that there is no need for mere hopes and wishes.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it seems odd to me in your example that git still can not attempt to make those changes to lines 87-89 and just force a conflict against what's already there (using `>>>>>>` and `<<<<<<`). And then I, the author, can manually accept one or the other. Appreciate the insight though, thanks!

Comment: The problem is that to construct a proper conflict, Git would have to find a *third* file, namely the common ancestor from which both your to-be-patched file has changes, and from which the patch you're applying has changes. That is, the patch you are applying says "make this change to lines 87-89" for instance—so Git *needs to find the file that has those lines as lines 87-89*, so that it can find which lines in *your* file correspond. Git can do this with some Git patches due to their `index` line: the `index` line contains the hash ID of the original file.

Comment: If your patches have the `index` lines, and you have that original file (as a stored blob in your repository), and you use `git apply --3way` or `git am --3way`, Git will attempt this. If you used `git format-patch` to produce the patches they will have index lines (and you can use `--full-index` to prevent abbreviations that may make them ambiguous), but those may not correspond to actual blobs in your repository.

Comment: Note that if you have *direct* access to repo A and wish to cherry-pick some commit(s) from it into unrelated repo B, you can `git fetch` A's commits into repo B, and then run `git cherry-pick` in repo B. This strategy *will* do a three-way merge and give you the conflict lines you'd like.

Comment: Thanks so much for the update and the detailed outline. That explanation makes great sense and the approach of adding another `remote` and doing a `git fetch` to merge in changes is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Note, you see:

```
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
```

But, as documented in Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), this is not quite true.

See [commit 80736d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80736d7c5eabe49062aeaea47b83eba2bb40314d) (23 Oct 2019) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f1e2666](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1e2666b332161c96b13c692c96ae39f0aa55612), 10 Nov 2019)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80736d7c5eabe49062aeaea47b83eba2bb40314d): `am --show-current-patch` gives an entire e-mail message
>
> The existing wording gives an impression that it only gives the contents of the `$GIT_DIR/rebase-apply/patch` file, i.e. the patch proper, **but the option actually emits the entire e-mail message being processed (iow, one of the output files from "git mailsplit")**.

So you might have to extract from that email the exact part which causes conflicts.